# Why does my Matlab Random Shuffle not work?

Tags: matlab, shuffle, random

I tried figuring this out but it doesn't work.

Say I have

```
a = [5,1,5,6,7,2,4];
```

Now, if I do `a(randperm(a))` i get :

```
ans =

     1     7     6     5     5
```

Now, I also have

```
b = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
```

However, if I do `b(randperm(b))` :

```
ans =

     1
```

Why is this happening? This does not seem to make any sense to me. How do I shuffle a vector like :

```
z = [1,2,3,4.... 1500,6001,6002,6003... 8999];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

randperm takes a single N and returns a permutation of the numbers 1 to N.

I don't have Matlab installed so I can't try this out, but this should work:

```
a(randperm(length(a)))
```

Comment: But if I give my array z to it, it won't give me a shuffle but a random ordering of [1 to length(a)], Which is incorrect.

Comment: but if you index z by that vector, it should return the elements at all those indexes, right?

Answer (score 0):

The parameter of randperm should not be the array but it's length.
Try

```
B(randperm(length(B)))
```